# How can you control NVidia devices from Java on windows using MinGW/MSYS autotools?

Tags: java, gpu, nvapi

To be specific I am trying to read/write power settings, fan settings, and clock speed settings. I also need access to GPU temperature.  I attempted to do this from MingGW with Swig using the NVAPI library but it will not compile as MinGW's compiler doesn't understand the nvapi.h header file. I have scanned through JCuda but I can't locate any functions in JCuda for accessing these driver settings.

Note: I have already successfully been able to access all of this functionality from the AMD-SDK for AMD video cards which had no problems compiling with MinGW

Visual studio is NOT an option for this project because it is part of a larger project that uses the autotools build system. For linux I should be able to wrap the XNVCtrl library using swig so the only compatibility gap is the windows-nvidea combination.

One final note: All kernels will be modular in this system so if the kernels need to be compiled with visual studio that isn't a problem but the control system itself needs to be built with autotools and accessible from Java.

Answer (score 1):

After many headaches I found I was able to wrap the NVML library with swig using the GPU Deployment Kit.  The build environment still needs some adjustments to support linux but an alpha version of this system is available at https://github.com/rritoch/WarpCTL/tree/master/extra/JNVML